# Where is Float#to_d?

Tags: ruby

Sometimes I see code using `to_d`. The ruby documentation even states [there is a `Float#to_d` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/Float.html). However, it's not in my version of ruby (`ruby 1.9.3p263 (2012-08-23 revision 36792`).

```
1.9.3p263 :001 > "0.0".to_d
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_d' for "0.0":String
    from (irb):1
    from /home/iblue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3p263 :002 > 0.0.to_d
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_d' for 0.0:Float
    from (irb):2
    from /home/iblue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3p263 :003 > 0.to_d
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_d' for 0:Fixnum
    from (irb):3
    from /home/iblue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

No `to_d` in `Float`, `String` or `Fixnum`. What's going on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As stated in the [example of the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/Float.html) you need

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'
```